# TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain) django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to create a new project. The technologies that I am using for the project are Python 3.8 and Django. I've just gotten stuck with an error and I can not move forward.
This is the error I'm getting when I run the server with `python3 manage.py runserver`

> raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html
> [25/Oct/2020 00:15:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 73916

I believe this means I am not able access to the template that I've created.
I created a "templates" folder under my "users app".
The root of the templates folder is in the same root with my project app.
I updated my project setting templates like this:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

My URLs to the path in my project folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/',include('users.urls')),
    path('users/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'),name='home'),
]
```

My user app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns=[
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(),name='signup'),
]
```

home.html looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Home {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

{% if %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome {{user.username}}!
    <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Exit</a></p>
{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in!!!</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Register</a></p>

{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

view.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

# Create your views here.

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class=CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name="signup.html"
```

I looked for solutions on StackOverflow and they mostly mentioned about changing settings.py in project folder, which I've already done, but it did not fix my problem. Could you please help me how to solve this problem to continue my project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try: template_name='<your_model_name>/home.html'

Answer (score 0):

what is your app structure,beacuse this line `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`  should not be static. to solve my issue i had to specify the location of the templates folder like this. `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/templates')],`